# Arranging Buttons on a Process Enumerating Application

Tags: c#, algorithm, winforms

I had the following piece of code for populating a list of currently running processes in an IT Self-Help application :

```
var proclist = ProcessHelper.GetProcList();

var i = 0;
var j = 0;

foreach (var process in proclist)
{
    if (process.ButtonText == "") continue;
    var button = new Button();

    if (i < 7)
    {
        button.Location = new Point(10, 30 * i + 65);
    }
    else if ((i > 6) & (i < 14))
    {
        button.Location = new Point(150, 30 * j + 65);
        j++;
    }
    else
    {
        button.Location = new Point(290, 30 * j + 65);
        j++;
    }

    i++;

    button.Click += (x, y) => button.Visible = false;
    button.Click += (x, y) => process.Kill();

    button.Text = process.ButtonText;

    button.Image = process.ThumbNail;
    button.ImageAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;

    processTab.Controls.Add(button);

    button.Width = 130;
    button.Height = 25;
    button.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft; 
}
```

And today I realised, that if a user has more than 14 applications running, my logic falls apart on the third column and displays the items like this :

[image]

I managed to fix this with the following amendment (added a new variable for the third column) :

```
var proclist = ProcessHelper.GetProcList();

// For placing each button - need a var for each column 
var i = 0;
var j = 0;
var k = 0;

foreach (var process in proclist)
{
    if (process.ButtonText == "") continue;
    var button = new Button();

    if (i < 7)
    {
        button.Location = new Point(10, 30 * i + 65);
    }
    else if ((i > 6) & (i < 14))
    {
        button.Location = new Point(150, 30 * j + 65);
        j++;
    }
    else
    {
        button.Location = new Point(290, 30 * k + 65);
        k++;
    }

    i++;

    button.Click += (x, y) => button.Visible = false;
    button.Click += (x, y) => process.Kill();

    button.Text = process.ButtonText;

    button.Image = process.ThumbNail;
    button.ImageAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;

    processTab.Controls.Add(button);

    button.Width = 130;
    button.Height = 25;
    button.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft; 
}
```

And now the items appear correctly :

[image]

However, I couldn't help but think that this is not a very clean fix, because I just hard-coded in another column, and if a user every has 21 + applications open, the issue will occur again!

finally, I came up with this :

```
var i = 0;
var j = 0;
var column = 10;

foreach (var process in proclist)
{
    if (process.ButtonText == "") continue;
    var button = new Button();

    if ((i > 0) & ((i % 7) == 0))
    {
        j = 0;
        column = column + 140;
    }

    button.Location = new Point(column, 30 * j + 65);

    j++;
    i++;

    button.Click += (x, y) => button.Visible = false;
    button.Click += (x, y) => process.Kill();

    button.Text = process.ButtonText;

    button.Image = process.ThumbNail;
    button.ImageAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;

    processTab.Controls.Add(button);

    button.Width = 130;
    button.Height = 25;
    button.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft; 
}
```

Which (as far as I can tell), will arrange the buttons correctly as long as there aren't so many that they go out of the window (which is highly unlikely in this environment). Here is a screenshot of the new version in action :

[image]

Hopefully this is the right place to post this - any feedback is extremely welcome!

Comment: So many Internet Explorer :o

Comment: @Phrancis haha ye, never seen quite as many as in the last image but  some people still don't seem to have grasped the concept of using tabs!

Comment: It would be more readable if you name the numbers  and give the counters  (j and i) more descriptive names ;)

Comment: Your `Button` instances live and die within the loop scope. How/where do you tell them that *something* should happen when they're clicked?

Comment: @Mat'sMug I didn't include this as my question was about the placement, but I have now updated with that detail in case you were interested. Both `ButtonText` and `ThumbNail` are properties of my custom `Proc` class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What will happen when there are more processes than you can fit buttons for on your form?

You're doing the hard work by hand, reinventing a wheel that's already there for you... and as you saw, it's not exactly scaling very well.

The wheel in question is called a [FlowLayoutPanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel(v=vs.100).aspx), a [winforms](/questions/tagged/winforms) layout control that automatically handles control positioning for you, taking overflowing controls to a new row or column, depending on how you configured it - it even handles scrollbars for you, if you have more items than can fit into the panel.

---

That said, your wheel has a number of squeaky parts:

> ```
> if (process.ButtonText == "") continue;
> ```

- Comparing a string against an empty string, would usually be written like this:

  ```
  if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(process.ButtonText)
  {
      continue;
  }
  ```
- In all versions/attempts of your layout code, you hard-coded the key values.

  - `140` / the column width, should be computed from the width of a button
  - `7` is arbitrary and should be allowed to change if/when the form is maximized or resized. Your screenshots crop the top part, but if you haven't removed the min/maximize buttons and allow resizing of the form, the user can easily wreck your layout; it doesn't take the button height into consideration either.

---

### BUG?

It's a little beyond the scope of this review, but this line can potentially blow everything up:

> ```
> button.Click += (x, y) => process.Kill();
> ```

There's a chance your application will not-so-graciously crash and burn if you bring up your app, *then start task manager **and kill a process**, and then click the button for that process in your app*.

The process to kill won't exist anymore, and if `ProcessHelper.Kill()` doesn't handle that situation, boom! Make sure your wrapper wraps the operation in a `try..catch` block.

Comment: Thanks for the review! Actually saw the error you mention happen yesterday! For some reason ie creates 2 processes and I you kill the 'real' one the other also dies, meaning if you try killing it through the app the error appears! Will incorporate all of this in the new version thanks again!